# Validar correos y enviar mensaje de verificación

Tags: php

Hace ya tiempo que programé una sección de registro que entre otras cosas, validaba el correo y enviaba un email para poder verificar la cuenta. El caso es que me he fijado en que muchos usuarios se han registrado con cuentas distintas de gmail o hotmail, y el correo no se envía.

Para validar el correo uso filter_var:

```
$mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
$remail = trim($_POST['remail']);

$mail = filter_var($mail,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errores .= "Correo electrónico no válido </br>";
} else {
    if (strlen($mail) < 10) {
       $errores .= "El correo electrónico es demasiado corto </br>";
    }
    if ($mail != $remail) {
       $errores .= "Los correos no coinciden </br>";
    }
}
```

Si no hay errores en el formulario, envío un correo, y lo hago com `mail()`:

```
    $destinatario = $mail;

    $para  = $destinatario;


    // título
    $titulo= 'Verifica tu correo';

        // mensaje
        $mensaje = "
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Verifica tu correo</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>Bienvenido,</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";

    $cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    // Cabeceras adicionales
    $cabeceras .= "To: $para" . "\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= 'From: LaXtore <noreply@laXtore.com>' . "\r\n";

    mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Con hotmail y gmail no parece haber problema, y no sé si es debido a que `mail()` no soporta otras. ¿Debería simplemente no permitir que alguien se registre si no usa gmail o hotmail?

Comment: Tu problema, por cómo lo estás describiendo, no tiene nada que ver con la validación, sino con el SMTP que estás usando. Creo que para entender de qué se trata, hay que ver al menos un ejemplo de dirección de mail, y qué error aparece en el log de tu SMTP... Otra opción es que se estén enviando bien pero que el destino los rechace por algún motivo (spamhaus por ejemplo?), o que lleguen pero queden en la carpeta de spam y un usuario no se dé cuenta

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomendaría modificar la forma de validación antes que limitarte el número de usuarios de entrada a tu web.
Si restringes por correo, puedes estar evitando que muchos clientes potenciales, entren a tu web.

Podrías quizás hacerlo de esta forma.

1º en tu tabla de usuarios sitúas un valor BOOLEAN, que determina si esa cuenta de usuario está o no activa (verificada). Por defecto siempre estará en 0 / false.

2º Haces que en el login y reinicio de contraseña, no puedan continuar estos procesos a menos que la cuenta esté activada.

3º Siempre, en cada registro de usuario, generas un "TOKEN" o cadena de texto única asociada a ese usuario.
Puedes generarla a modo de función HASH.
Esto es, por ejemplo, obtienes 3 o 4 letras aleatorias de ese nombre + su ID única. Digamos que realizas una operación con la que obtener una cadena de texto que sabes que siempre va a ser única para ese usuario. "SWDH2SHW2DHSW4532kKSL".

Ahora, si el email existe, pues a ese email llegará un correo con un enlace, el cual debe visitar el cliente para activar su cuenta.

Si el email no existe, es cierto que generará una entrada de usuario, sin embargo mas adelante le daré solución a esto. De tal forma, al no existir el email, pues a nadie le llegará tal email para validarse.

Ahora, cuando el usuario visite ese enlace con su TOKEN

www.tuweb.com/verificandoUsuario/SWDH2SHW2DHSW4532kKSL,

realizando su correspondiente conexión conseguridad, haces que en la base de datos del usuario, se modifique el valor de activación de "false" a "ture", y borras su cadena de texto (TOKEN) de la base de datos.

De esta forma, la cuenta quedará verificada.

A su vez, puedes realizar 1 acción automática o denominada "cron" con la que limpiar la base de datos de usuarios que no hayan sido verificados en un periodo de por ejemplo, 15 días o 30 días. Sería algo así como, "usuarios con acceso de activación en false, que tengan una cadena de texto (TOKEN) y que se registraron hace mas de X tiempo, se eliminan.
Quizás sean emails inexistentes que han generado usuarios (posibles bot, trols...etc)

Por otra parte, ese valor de verificación de cuenta, te puede ayudar en el caso que necesites bloquear el acceso a un usuario desde la administración. 
Puedes cambiar el valor de boolean de "true" a "false", que, a su vez, al no tener TOKEN, ya que el usuario se habia registrado y verificado anteriormente, sabes que solo puede ser el caso de un usuario baneado.

En tus lógicas de: "verificar email (proceso para reenviar email de verificación) , cambio de contraseña o inicio de sesión", puedes poner que:

Si el usuario no esta verificado (FALSE) y su token está vacio (ya se consiguió verificar con anterioridad), el mensaje que debe dar es de "usuario baneado, pongase en contacto con...".

Si el usuario no esta verificado (FALSE) pero su token esta lleno, es que es nuevo usuario, y la respuesta será, "comprobar email para verificar su cuenta".

Si el usuario está verificado y su token vacío, es que está verificado y no baneado, le deja pasar.

Y recuerda por último, si el usuario, han pasado mas de X tiempo desde que se registró, (no esta verificado FALSE) y su token está lleno, es porque, o bien no existe tal email (un error del usuario, un bot, un troll...) o bien simplemente alguien se registró pero no terminó el proceso. Simplemente se eliminan estos usuarios, limpiando así tu base de datos. =)

No se si me explique del todo bien, cualquier duda, no dudes en comentar! :)

Saludos.

RESUMEN: Resumiendo un poco el concepto, sería pasarle al usuario la función de verificar su cuenta y permitiendo a cualquier tipo de email registrarse en vez de realizar tu la verificación con tu código de forma interna.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Lo cierto es que lo hago así, pero eso no impide que haya gente con extensiones raras de correo se registre. He visto de todo, y la mayoría ni las conocía, pero tengo realizado un sistema de verificación como el que comentas, con las diferencias de que el token lo mantengo porque no hago nada con él después, principalmente porque puede ser gente que no ha tenido tiempo de mirarlo o se ha olvidado o lo que sea. El problema creo que está en la función mail(), porque los correos pasan el filtro, pero no son enviados, al menos me encuentro con  muchos casos de esos.

Comment: De momento lo he limitado a gmail y hotmail sólo. Más que nada porque no me sirve que se registren si no pueden verificar la cuenta.

Comment: Ah claro, ahora entiendo la diferencia. Cuando dices que lo dejas (token) por si no han tenido tiempo de verificar, intuyo que les dejas acceder igual a la plataforma aunque no estén verificados y así que se verifiquen mas tarde. Sin embargo, yo lo tengo restringido. De tal forma que o verificas o no puedes acceder a nada. De esta forma un usuario que no se verifica en un tiempo considerable 30-60 dias..es porque no piensa acceder y será eliminado. Si lo desea se volverá a registrar :). No hay de que en la respuesta, estamos para ayudar :).

Comment: En realidad no pueden entrar hasta que se verifiquen, pero no les pongo esa restricción de 15 días. En cualquier caso mi problema no es de verificación, sino de enviar email a correos que no sean gmail o hotmail.

Comment: Hola @Sergio, disculpa que comente, tendrás un tiempo para unas consultas? me leí toda tu respuesta (entiendo que fue hace dos años), peor ahorita estoy implementando la autenticación en un pequeño proyecto personal y me encuentro un poco perdido.

Comment: Hola @JulianProg, disculpa pues llevo tiempo desconectado de stackoverflow por motivos personales. Díme, ¿en que puedo ayudarte? Creo que quizás podemos pasar al chat para evitar el spam de mensajes. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Sergio! Si, déjame el link cuando puedas

Comment: Puedes contactarme en privado al siguiente email: contactometemp@gmail.com